# Handling factors in caret classification with random forest

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest, prediction, r-caret

I am running random forests from caret in the following code:

```
library(quantmod)
library(Hmisc)
library(caret)

daysback=1
mlmodels=c("rf","knn")
my.df <- getSymbols(Symbols = "^FTSE", auto.assign = FALSE)
my.df=na.approx(my.df)
difvar=100*(my.df[,4]-my.df[,1])/my.df[,1]
data<-as.data.frame(difvar)
dframe=data.frame(ds=as.Date(rownames(data)),y=as.factor(sign(data[,1])))
for (i in 1:365) {
  eval(parse(text=paste0("dframe$y",i,"=Lag(dframe$y, +",i,")")))
}
dframe$year=as.numeric(format(dframe$ds,"%Y"))
dframe$month=as.numeric(format(dframe$ds,"%m"))
dframe$day=as.numeric(format(dframe$ds,"%d"))
dframe$dow=as.numeric(factor(weekdays(dframe$ds), levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", 
                                                             "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"),
                             ordered = TRUE))
dframe=dframe[complete.cases(dframe),]
start=nrow(dframe)-daysback
end=nrow(dframe)
actual_sign=data.frame(act=sign(dframe$y),date=dframe$ds)

#Run each model for m symbol

  rf_f=data.frame()
  res=list()

  ##Forecast data prep
  for (j in start:end){
    print(j)
    dframetmp=dframe[1:j,]

    m_rf = train(y~.-ds, data=dframetmp, method="rf")

  }
```

As you can see my y and x's are all categorical variables. Year,month, day, day of the week and lagged values of y which is also categorical.
Apart from putting some code to convert all these to factors, do I have to do sth else like creating dummy variables?
Any optimization suggestion?

Thanks a lot
George

Comment: yes you are going to have to convert them to dummy variables. Take a look at the package called dummies

Comment: You want to optimize speed? Accuracy? Something else? If it's accuracy, I'd suggest trying different approaches (i.e. factors, dummy variables, or numeric values for days and months) and use cross-validation methods to determine which is better for you. Maybe additional lagged values could improve accuracy (e.e lag 2, 3, etc.). Or any other feature engineering you can apply to your current variables.

Comment: @AdamWarner Thanks! Do i still to convert them to dummies even if they are defined as factors?

Comment: @AntoniosK Thanks! I already have lagged 365. Do you think i need more?

Comment: @GeorgiosKourogiorgas whenever I used caret I had to use dummy variables. There is even a built in function in caret called dummyVars. Also take a look at the package mlr, that way you can do custom cost functions!!

Comment: @AdamWarner you can use dummy variables, but it's not necessary, especially in the case of random forest. Maybe the model you used wanted dummy variables in order to use a number??

Comment: @GeorgiosKourogiorgas you have lagged 365 or up to lagged 365? :) maybe also group past time-frame into previous month, previous month -1, etc. But it's better to start from somewhere, use that as your baseline and spend time to improve it as much as you can, rather than start with the ideal model. It will save you time and it will be easier to debug in case you have any problems. It will also give you the satisfaction of improving something step by step :)

Comment: @AntoniosK definitely possible. I think I was also crossing over from Python world, which as we all know cannot hang like R can.

Comment: Also use `method = "ranger"` instead of `method = rf`. The random forest of `ranger` is a lot faster than `randomForest()` function from `randomForest`.